# Change icon dynamically in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have two icons for "Like" button - `ic_thumb_up` and `ic_thumb_up_selected`

The type of icon should depend on the `offer.likedByUser` parameter.

```
var thumbIcon by remember {
    mutableStateOf(if (offer.likedByUser) R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_selected else R.drawable.ic_thumb_up)
}

IconButton(
    onClick = {
        offer.likedByUser = !offer.likedByUser
    } 
) {
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = thumbIcon) )
}
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code

```
var thumbIcon by remember {
   mutableStateOf(if (offer.likedByUser) R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_selected else R.drawable.ic_thumb_up)
}
```

runs only once, and sets the value to either `thumbs_up_selected` or `thumbs_up`. You are not changing the `mutableStateOf` in your `onClick` handler, so nothing happens.

You need to change it like this

```
var thumbIconLiked by remember {
   mutableStateOf(offer.likedByUser)
}

IconButton(
    onClick = {
        thumbIconLiked = !thumbIconLiked
    } 
) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(
            id = if (thumbIconLIked) { 
                R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_selected 
            } else { 
                R.drawable.ic_thumb_up 
            },
            contenDescription = "thumb",
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Works great